# Is there a way to alter a node save confirmation form?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I would like to add a confirmation form that is presented to a user on node update/delete operations triggered through the UI.

Specifically, I would like the form to present more than two choices for the user. i.e. instead of Submit/Cancel I would Option A/Option B/Option C.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I was writing a huge response before regarding [confirm_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/confirm_form/7) in Drupal 7. I recommend you google and look at the examples module for confirm_form usage.

In short you probably want to:

- use hook_form_alter to override the #submit or #action (or pre-pend to the list) the form will send to.
- then you want to show a new form -- just like confirm_form does and do more logic in your custom confirmation form submit handler.
- then redirect wherever using `drupal_goto` for instance or `$form['#redirect']`.

This may sound vague -- but the Form API can do all of this. You just have alot of learning to do. I have used confirm_form. I've made workflows for 8 Node forms to wizard through 8 Node add forms; and even made a "login" form fake login people from a login form completely overridden with a dropdown list of students on a Test server (to mock out users) using hook_form_alter().

Drupal can do all of this -- you just have to read the API and look at examples and experiment until you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  So, I basically need to create a similar function to confirm_form but with multiple choices?

Comment: essentially. also look at how confirm_form is linked into like the node delete operations in the default `node.module` file (or 1 of the `node` form files ... it might be node.pages.inc or something similar.

Comment: "Drupal can do all of this -- you just have to read the API and look at examples and experiment until you get what you want." This. Yes. A hundred times yes. And Form API is one of the deeper parts of the Drupal pool in my experience :)