# How can I rebuild a node edit form and hide all elements except confirmation buttons

Tags: nodes, forms

In another question I asked [Is there a way to alter a node save confirmation form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85272/is-there-a-way-to-alter-a-node-save-confirmation-form).  The recommendation was to use hook_form_alter to append a callback to the submit handler that would redirect to a new form where I could implement my confirmation logic.

I have experimented with this and come up short in a couple of areas.  One is ensuring that  callbacks from other modules are not affected.  The other is getting data in the form and form_state arrays from the node edit form to the confirmation form where I can act on it.  It seems that an alternate solution is to use multi-step techniques and 'rebuild' the node edit form like the preview action does.

How can I ensure that when I rebuild the form with some confirmation options that the other form elements are hidden?  In other words I just want a clean form but still retain access to the form and form_state data.  Is there a form property that does this?

Comment: Not quite clear what are you trying to do; why you just don't hide unnecessary form elements with `$form['element']['#access'] = FALSE;`?

Comment: Well, I could use that or one of the [other techniques](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41748/specify-form-elements-to-be-excluded-from-display).  I also found [this useful](http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2009/may/29/multi_step_node_forms_drupal_6) useful.  But I thought maybe there was a way to know which elements can be hidden.